# Transpose the MySQL output to go "down the page" instead of "across the page?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query working great thanks to the help of John Ruddell.
The output looks like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| Jan   |   Feb  |  Mar  |  Apr  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Aug | etc..
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 13050 |  5200  | 48450 | 34041 | 38000 | 0     | 0     | 0    |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

```html
SELECT 
    t1.Average, t2.weekly_average, 
    IF(t1.Jan + t2.Jan_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Jan + t2.Jan_webl) AS Jan_Total, 
    IF(t1.Feb + t2.Feb_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Feb + t2.Feb_webl) AS Feb_Total,
    IF(t1.Mar + t2.Mar_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Mar + t2.Mar_webl) AS Mar_Total,
    IF(t1.Apr + t2.Apr_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Apr + t2.Apr_webl) AS Apr_Total,
    IF(t1.May + t2.May_webl IS NULL,0,t1.May + t2.May_webl) AS May_Total,
    IF(t1.Jun + t2.Jun_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Jun + t2.Jun_webl) AS Jun_Total,
    IF(t1.Jul + t2.Jul_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Jul + t2.Jul_webl) AS Jul_Total,
    IF(t1.Aug + t2.Aug_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Aug + t2.Aug_webl) AS Aug_Total,
    IF(t1.Sep + t2.Sep_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Sep + t2.Sep_webl) AS Sep_Total,
    IF(t1.Oct + t2.Oct_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Oct + t2.Oct_webl) AS Oct_Total,
    IF(t1.Nov + t2.Nov_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Nov + t2.Nov_webl) AS Nov_Total,
    IF(t1.Dec + t2.Dec_webl IS NULL,0,t1.Dec + t2.Dec_webl) AS Dec_Total,
    t1.Total, t2.total_webl
FROM
(  SELECT 
      AVG(febl_remaining) as 'Average',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jan',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Feb',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Mar',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Apr',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN febl_remaining END) 'May',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jun',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jul',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Aug',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Sep',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Oct',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Nov',
      MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Dec',
      SUM(febl_remaining) as 'Total'
   FROM
   (   SELECT 
       1 as id, 
       DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,   
       IF 
       (   SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, 
             SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth), 
             SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)
       ) AS febl_remaining
   FROM      tblweeklyebl 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
   WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
   ) t 
   GROUP BY t.id
) t1
JOIN
(  SELECT 
      SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) / 
      COUNT(DISTINCT   
         IF(tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth = 0, NULL, MONTH(tblweeklyebl.weDate))
      ) AS weekly_Average,
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec_webl',
      SUM(DISTINCT tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) AS Total_webl    
   FROM      tblweeklyebl 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID
) t2
```

- How do I transpose the output to go "down the page" instead of "across the page?

Need it to group this way:

```
Jan 13050
Feb 5200
Mar 48450
Apr 34041
May 38000
Jun 0
Jul 0
Aug 0
Sep 0
Oct 0
Nov 0
Dec 0
```

Comment: Holy heck that is a nasty query..

Comment: Start again. The whole point of that monster query was so months could run across the page.

Comment: The subquery returns the information down the page, the outer query is pivoting it. So just get rid of the pivot.

Comment: This query needs all of the sub-queries in order to produce the correct output.. but I now need to plot those same results on my chart, which requires the results in the two-column, down the page format.. Do I need to wrap it in another pivot statement?